# SwiftUI onTapGesture tappable area is larger than shape

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I'm learning SwiftUI and had a very simple view with only one shape with a `onTapGesture`. What I'm expecting the `onTapGesture` should be called only when I click on the shape. However I've noticed that when I click outside of the shape (not too far away) the `onTapGesture` is also fired. Any one has any idea why this is happening?

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10)
            .fill(Color.yellow)
            .frame(width: 100, height: 100, alignment: .leading)
            .onTapGesture {
                print("Clicked")
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Update:

I've tried having multiple element inside a `Vstack`. When you try to click on the very bottom of `test view2` you can see in the console that it prints `click on view 3`.

```
var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ZStack {
                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20)
                    .foregroundColor(.red)
                Text("test view1")
            }
            .frame(width: 200, height: 100, alignment: .center)
            ZStack {
                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20)
                    .foregroundColor(.blue)
                Text("test view2")
            }
                .frame(width: 200, height: 100, alignment: .center)
            .onTapGesture {
                print("click on view 2")
            }
            ZStack {
                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20)
                    .foregroundColor(.green)
                Text("test view3")
            }
                .frame(width: 200, height: 100, alignment: .center)
            .onTapGesture {
                print("click on view 3")
            }

        }
        .frame( maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .bottom)
        .background(Color.black)
    }
```

Comment: It is finger spot not a cursor hot point.

Comment: @Asperi Thanks for your comment. But in this case if I have two of the elements inside a `VStack` then wouldn't the touch area overlap with eachother?

Comment: @Asperi I've updated my question to show this issue

Comment: I'm also struggling with this, did you find anything helpful?